# Using superclass's convenience initializers in subclass instantiation

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

This occurred in a playground in XCode6-Beta5

I'm trying to add some functionality to `SKSpriteNode` in a subclass, `Sprite`, but I still want to use the convenience initializers in `SKSpriteNode`. However, I get the following error:

```
"Cannot convert the expression's type 'Sprite' to type 'Sprite'"
```

from this code:

```
import Cocoa
import SpriteKit

class Sprite : SKSpriteNode {
    // The following code makes this not compile
    // required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    //     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    // }
}

var sprite = Sprite(imageNamed: "Rayman1.png") // Error occurs on this line
```

The convenience initializer in question is declared like this:

```
convenience init(imageNamed name: String!)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Initializer Chaining** rules as specified in the Swift Programming Guide, which reads:

> Designated initializers must call a designated initializer from their immediate superclass.

If you are calling superclass's convenience initialize in sub class instantiation then this is not allowed.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: What the hell? That's ridiculous! How am I supposed to ever use that initializer in my subclass?

Comment: A Nice and brief discussion.

http://www.codingricky.com/construtor-chaining-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

I had to get rid of the `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)` method, and that fixed everything. I have no idea why.